# How to Calculate and Displays NFL Passer Rating?

Tags: java

I am trying to do this homework problem but I am having difficulties setting it up and understanding how to start and accomplish these results.

This is the screenshot of the formulas:

[image: screenshot of the formulas]

[link if the image is not showing] https://screenshot.net/pdg9piy?

So far I've declared the variables for the formulas, created a scanner and tried to write the formula.
This is what I have so far:

```
  //declaring variables
  float a_CompletionPercentage, b_YardsPerAttempt, c_TouchdownsPerAttempt, d_InterceptionsPerAttempt;
  float PasserRating;
  double Completion, Attempts, Touchdowns, Yards, Interceptions;


  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //create Scanner Object


  //PlayerName input
  System.out.print("Enter the full name of the quarterback: "); //prompt asks for player name
  String PlayerName = in.nextLine(); //set string PlayerName as user's input

  //attempts input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of attempts: "); //prompt asks for # of attempts
  Attempts = in.nextDouble(); //set variable Attempts as user's input for # of attempts

  //completion input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of completions: "); 
  Completion = in.nextDouble(); 

  //yards input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of yards: "); 
  Yards = in.nextDouble();

  //touchdowns input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of touchdowns: "); 
  Touchdowns = in.nextDouble(); 

  //interceptions input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of interceptions: "); 
  Interceptions = in.nextDouble(); 

  //calculations 
  a_CompletionPercentage = (((float)(Completion/Attempts)- 0.3f) * 5f); //formula for completion percentage
  b_YardsPerAttempt = (((float)(Yards/Attempts)- 3f) * 5f); //formula for yards per attempt
  c_TouchdownsPerAttempt = ((float)(Touchdowns/Attempts) * 20f); //formula for touchdowns per attempt
  d_InterceptionsPerAttempt = (2.375f - ((float)(Interceptions/Attempts) * 25f)); //formula for interceptions per attempt

  PasserRating = (((a_CompletionPercentage + b_YardsPerAttempt + c_TouchdownsPerAttempt + d_InterceptionsPerAttempt)/6)*100f); //formula for passing rate


  //Displays result
  System.out.println("The passer rating for " + PlayerName + " is " + PasserRating);
```

I am not sure if my variables were declared correctly and my formula is not working.

These are some sample outputs that I should be getting:
Output Sample 1:

Enter the full name of the quarterback: Jameis Winston

Enter the number of attempts: 35

Enter the number of completions: 22

Enter the number of yards: 345

Enter the number of touchdowns: 4

Enter the number of interceptions: 1

The passer rating for Jameis Winston is 121.72619047619047

But I am getting 664.58325 and not 121.72619047619047.

PLEASE HELP!

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ANYONE THAT TAKES THE TIME TO HELP ME WITH THIS!

Answer (score 1):

Your formula was incorrect.

Here:

```
b_YardsPerAttempt = (((float)(Yards/Attempts)- 3f) * 5f);
```

You're multiplying the result of (yards/attempts - 3) with 5 when you should be multiplying with 0.25. That's where your calculations took a wrong turn.

Please keep in mind that you shouldn't name your variables with capital starting letters. Also, it's good practice to declare new variables right before you plan on using them.
Here's a snippet for you to see how it could be written a little bit better.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the full name of the quarterback: ");
String playerName = in.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter the number of attempts: ");
Double attempts = in.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Enter the number of completions: ");
Double completion = in.nextDouble();


System.out.print("Enter the number of yards: ");
Double yards = in.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Enter the number of touchdowns: ");
Double touchdowns = in.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Enter the number of interceptions: ");
Double interceptions = in.nextDouble();

Double completionPercentage = ((completion / attempts - 0.3) * 5);
Double yardsPerAttempt = (((yards / attempts) - 3) * 0.25);
Double touchdownsPerAttempt = ((touchdowns / attempts) * 20);
Double interceptionsPerAttempt = (2.375 - ((interceptions / attempts) * 25));

Double passerRating = (((completionPercentage + yardsPerAttempt + touchdownsPerAttempt + interceptionsPerAttempt) / 6) * 100);

System.out.println("The passer rating for " + playerName + " is " + passerRating);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice helpful answer! Incidentally, `Scanner.nextDouble()` returns a primitive `double` (lower case "d"). If you want even cleaner code, you could declare all those variables as primitive `double`s instead. It's often good to avoid [boxed types](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-with-java-boxed-numbers) like `Double` unless you need nullability, or need to add them to a collection.

Comment: Good point. Thank you for your positive feedback

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the usual Java coding conventions for variable names, etc.  This makes your code less readable.  Start by learning them.

Like most novice programmers, you've focused too much of your efforts on inputs and not enough a writing a correct function.

It is not too early to learn about [JUnit](https://www.junit.org)
I'd recommend writing five functions:

```
public interface PasserRatingCalculator {
    default double calculateCompletionPercentage(int numAttempts, int numCompletions) { return ((double)numCompletions)/numAttempts; }
    double calculateYardsPerAttempt(int numAttempts, int numYards) { return ((double)numYards/numAttempts; }
    double calculateTouuchdownsPerAttempt(int numAttempts, int numTouchdowns) { return ((double)numTouchdowns)/numAttempts; }
    double calculateInterceptionsPerAttempt(int numAttempts, int numInterceptions) { return ((double)numInterceptions)/numAttempts; }
    double calculatePasserRating(numAttempts, int numCompletions, int numYards, int numTouchdowns, int numCompletions);        
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by myself.
As @duffymo said above, I was having problems with the declaration of the variables and its formats.

I've fixed the code and now it works as needed if anyone is interested here is my final working code:

```
 //declaring variables
  double a_CompletionPercentage, b_YardsPerAttempt, c_TouchdownsPerAttempt, d_InterceptionsPerAttempt;
  double PasserRating;
  int Completion, Attempts, Touchdowns, Yards, Interceptions;


  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //create Scanner Object


  //PlayerName input
  System.out.print("Enter the full name of the quarterback: "); //prompt asks for player name
  String PlayerName = in.nextLine(); //set string PlayerName as user's input

  //attempts input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of attempts: "); //prompt asks for # of attempts
  Attempts = in.nextInt(); //set variable Attempts as user's input for # of attempts

  //completion input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of completions: "); 
  Completion = in.nextInt(); 

  //yards input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of yards: "); 
  Yards = in.nextInt();

  //touchdowns input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of touchdowns: "); 
  Touchdowns = in.nextInt(); 

  //interceptions input
  System.out.print("Enter the number of interceptions: "); 
  Interceptions = in.nextInt(); 

  //calculations 
  if (Attempts == 0) {
        System.out.println("The passer rating for " + PlayerName + " is " + 0);

  } else {

     a_CompletionPercentage = ((double)Completion /Attempts - 0.3) * 5.0; //formula for completion percentage
     b_YardsPerAttempt =      ((double)Yards      /Attempts - 3.0) * 0.25; //formula for yards per attempt
     c_TouchdownsPerAttempt = ((double)Touchdowns /Attempts)       * 20.0; //formula for touchdowns per attempt
     d_InterceptionsPerAttempt = 2.375f - ((double)Interceptions /Attempts * 25.0); //formula for interceptions per attempt

     //formula for passing rate
     PasserRating = (((a_CompletionPercentage + b_YardsPerAttempt + c_TouchdownsPerAttempt + d_InterceptionsPerAttempt)/6.0) * 100.0); 


     //Displays result
     if (PasserRating < 0){
        System.out.println("The passer rating for " + PlayerName + " is " + 0);
     } else{
        System.out.println("The passer rating for " + PlayerName + " is " + PasserRating);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out! Please do listen to all the folks who are talking about variable naming conventions and declaring variables at the point of first use. In particular, @bjaklic's answer is much more readable to someone who is familiar with Java conventions.